# What generates this message: "*** SECURITY information for hostname ***"?

Tags: ubuntu, security

almost every time I use one Asus laptop I receive this email:

> subject *** SECURITY information for hostname ***
>
> hostname : May 17 10:50:36 : user : `浂

The symbol after the user field is always different and I don't know what this means. The installation and configuration is the same as for few other workstations, but I don't have such a notifications from them. The OS is Ubuntu 9.10.

Does anyone knows what this message is about?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is related to [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/627472). The user reports [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1565054) that it is related to a change of hostname.

Check your `/etc/hosts` file and make sure you have an entry pointing to your hostname.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the Sudo program or whatever it is sent this message as an alert that there was an invalid password attempt while trying to use sudo.

When I run `sudo visudo`, there is a setting `Defaults    mail_badpass` that I assume is the source of this.

Further evidence that this is from the sudo program / whatever it is called:
https://groups.google.com/g/rcdevs-technical/c/oUzjW0MZs_8?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

```bash
echo 'Defaults !mail_badpass' | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/disable_mail_badpass
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/986696/stop-emailing-me-bad-sudo-password-attempts

Comment: Can you explain a bit why this solves OP problem? Instead of just linking and write a code.